# Fill UITableView with Data from XML

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

In my Iphone App i want to fill my UITableView with Data from an XML File which i get from an Webservice. I get already the correct data and i can also parse it with RaptureXML.
I make some database queries before (Login/Authorization) and then get the Xml (File with Messages).
My problem is that the UITableView do not get any data.

Here is my method to fill data to the table:

```
if([responseString isEqualToString:@"true"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Iphone successfully registered !");

        NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pathtomywebservice/"];



        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
        [httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];
        [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/xml"];

        NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                udid, @"uuid",
                                nil];

        [httpClient postPath:@"getvMess" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            // reponseObject will hold the data returned by the server.

            NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"response: %@", responseString);

            RXMLElement *rxml = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLString:responseString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            subjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            senders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            texts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            channels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            NSArray *apps = [rxml children:@"ifxMessage"];
            [rxml iterateElements:apps usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *appElement) {

                [subjects addObject:[appElement child:@"subject"].text];
                NSLog(@"%@",[appElement child:@"subject"].text);
                [times addObject:[appElement child:@"time"].text];
                [texts addObject:[appElement child:@"text"].text];
                [senders addObject:[appElement child:@"sender"].text];
                [channels addObject:[appElement child:@"receiver"].text];                                        


            }];


        }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error retrieving data: %@", error);
        }];

    }


}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error retrieving data: %@", error);
}];
```

and here the specific code to fill the table:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [subjects count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // Configure the cell...
    // A cell identifier which matches our identifier in IB
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    // Create or reuse a cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Get the cell label using its tag and set it
    UILabel *cellLabelSubject = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    [cellLabelSubject setText:[subjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    //Get the cell's channel and its tag and set it
    UILabel *cellLabelChannel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    [cellLabelChannel setText:[channels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    //Get the cell's text and its tag and set it
    UITextView *cellTextViewText = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
    [cellTextViewText setText:[texts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    //Get the cell's time and its tag and set it
    UILabel *cellLabelTime = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
    [cellLabelTime setText:[times objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    //Get the cell's sender and its tag and set it
    UILabel *cellLabelSender = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:6];
    [cellLabelSender setText:[senders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];



    // get the cell imageview using its tag and set it
    UIImageView *cellImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    [cellImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%new_message.png", indexPath.row]]];

    return cell;
}
```

But when i fill the table from a local xml File it works fine:

```
subjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            senders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            texts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            channels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            RXMLElement *rxml = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLFile:@"Messages.xml"];

            NSArray *apps = [rxml children:@"ifxMessage"];
            [rxml iterateElements:apps usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *appElement) {

                [subjects addObject:[appElement child:@"subject"].text];
                [times addObject:[appElement child:@"time"].text];
                [texts addObject:[appElement child:@"text"].text];
                [senders addObject:[appElement child:@"sender"].text];
                [channels addObject:[appElement child:@"receiver"].text];



            }];
```

Comment: do u nsloag your all array before calling tableview?

Comment: not all, but the values are correct

Comment: IF your "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method is not calling, then you need to check that you are getting values in "Subject" array. As you are returning no. of raws count is Subject arr's count.

Comment: the array has valid values in it

Answer (score 1):

Because You are not adding your label,text...etc into cell...

```
[cell addSubview:cellLabelSubject];
[cell addSubview:cellLabelChannel];
[cell addSubview:cellTextViewText];
[cell addSubview:cellLabelTime];
[cell addSubview:cellLabelSender];
[cell addSubview:cellImage];
```

Comment: no thats not the problem, the problem is the tableView method (- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath) does not get called >.<

Comment: when i add data to the table from a local xml file, it works fine, i added this to the question above

Comment: Just check your table delegate and datasource connection....and make sure that there is some data before putting in table..

Comment: datasource and delegate is alright, data is also in the arrays